# Adding elements to a StaticBox in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to learn wxpython to do graphic Interfaces in python. 
My desired Interface should have 2 StaticBoxes and one button which should be in the first staticbox. I want something like that:

```
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|  #####                                       |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

I don´t know why I am getting the button in the upper left corner and I suspect that I configurated it wrong and that is why it is out of the staticbox. I am getting something like this:

```
######-----------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

My code is:

```
class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(600,600))

    # Defining panel
    panel = wx.Panel(self,-1)

    # Elements of the frame
    staticBoxUno = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, 'Uno:', pos=wx.Point(-1, -1), size=wx.Size(600, 150), style=0)
    staticBoxUno.SetOwnFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, 'MS Shell Dlg'))

    staticBoxDos = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, 'Dos:', pos=wx.Point(-1, -1), size=wx.Size(600, -1), style=0)
    staticBoxDos.SetOwnFont(wx.Font(8, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False, 'MS Shell Dlg'))

    buttonUno = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK")

    #Initialization Sizers
    boxMadre = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    boxMadre.AddSpacer(5)
    boxMadre.Add(staticBoxUno, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0)
    boxMadre.AddSpacer(5)
    boxMadre.Add(staticBoxDos, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0)

    staticBoxUnoSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(staticBoxUno, wx.VERTICAL)
    staticBoxUnoSizer.Add(buttonUno, -1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

    panel.SetSizer(boxMadre)
    panel.Layout()

app = wx.App(redirect=True)   # Error messages go to popup window
top = Frame("<<project>>")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I guess the problem is going to be when I try to add the button to the StaticBoxUno but I don´t know exactly what is failing

Thanks a lot!
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follows:

```
    # …
    buttonUno = wx.Button(panel, -1, "OK")

    staticBoxUnoSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(staticBoxUno, wx.VERTICAL)
    # use 0 instead of -1 as proportion in sizer
    staticBoxUnoSizer.Add(buttonUno, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

    # …
    # add sizer instead of StaticBox!
    boxMadre.Add(staticBoxUnoSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot nepix32, it works now. I have to add the sizer and not the staticbox itself.